# using MS XLSB instead of MS XLS

Tags: excel, xlsb

I need opinion on switching from MS XLS to XLSB. I have several models on MS xls file (Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet .xls) and have been using those models since many years. The xls files has lot of data, it has formula, macros, add-ins, formula to pull data from databases such as Bloomberg, Factset or Haver. I am planning to shift the model from MS Xls to MS xlsb i.e. binary format, however want to be sure if everything would work fine in binary format.

Can you please let me know if MS xls files are completely compatible with MS xlsb? ? Is there any disadvantage of using XLSB? Would be really thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

XLS and XLSB are different file formats.  The big disadvantage of XLSB is that it only works in Excel 2007+, so you can't depend on add-ins that only work in Excel 2000.

If your file works correctly in Excel 2007 or 2010 or 2013, then XLSB will preserve every feature from the XLS.  This is different from XLSX, where many features are intentionally omitted.